# I have cells at the beginning of a spreadsheet that appear blank

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, cells

I have a spreadsheet that was sent me that has blank columns on cols a-h.
However these are not blank as towards the end of the spreadsheet formulas refer to these.
How do I see the contents of cells a-h

Comment: Add up the formulas of every cell on post.

Comment: check if there is conditional formatting applied, and/or paint the cells with a different color

Comment: Have tried that I'm afraid but thanks for the suggestion.There is conditional formatting and the sheet is not protected

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the blank cells and the formulas which have results in them?

Comment: As LPChip suggested the first thing I would check is the font colour (could be white on a white background)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a screen grab. The formula that refers to cells a-h are contained in the green area on the right not in the green below the blue rows:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SU!  FYI your screenshot was not displaying correctly so I edited it back in

Comment: Please don't create a new user and post an answer to your question when you want to provide more information. Instead, login using the user you created the question with and edit your post.